# Avoid cross join

Tags: sql-server, join, cross-join

I have three tables: Student, Question and Answer. Answer has FK to both Student and Question.
I used a cross join on students and questions:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fetch_AnswersForStudents]
    @studentIds [Int_udtt] READONLY
    , @questionIds [Int_udtt] READONLY

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        [tQID].[Id]
        , ISNULL([tA].[StudentId], 0) AS StudentId
        , [tA].[Answer] AS Answer
    FROM
        @questionIds AS tQID        
        CROSS JOIN @studentIds AS tSID        
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Answer AS tA 
            ON tA.QuestionId = tQID.Id            
            AND tA.StudentId = tSID.Id 

END
```

The purpose of this proc is to determine whether students/questions given have corresponding answers. My question is, is there a way not using cross join to achieve the same goal? In addition, it is best to return a set that has answer entries.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply join across Answer? That is, select from Answer and JOIN to both the student and question tables?

Comment: Ahh, yes, if result set is null, then the result is not all question/student have answer. My original problem actually also involves returns the set for other purposes, so I simplified to use this example, which turns out to be missing one requirement.

Comment: Update question to reflect the other requirement.

Comment: So my understanding is this: For a set of students X and a set of questions Y, determine if any students have answers for any of the questions. Aside from an answer, there is no relationship between student and question. Is that correct? If so, for each student, for each question, an answer either exists or is NULL. That sounds like a cartesian product (cross join) to me. Let's try something else: what do you want your **result set** to look like?

Comment: To be more specific: let's consider one question, for which no students have answers. How should that question appear in your resultset, if not associated to every student with a NULL answer?